# Web service work but return error

Tags: ajax, web-services

My web service work fine but return error after send email succesfuly.

Example:

```
function callJsonSync(toVal, subjectVal, bodyVal) {
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "service.asmx/SendEmailWebService?callback=?",
                data: { to: toVal, subject: subjectVal,body: bodyVal},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert("YES");
                },
                error: function (data) {

                   alert("NO");
                }

            });
        }
```

All work fine, after call web service in HTML page, but always go in error!

Any reason for that?

Comment: get status of error..may be you will get an idea..like `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            } else {
                    alert('Unexpected error.');
            }
    }`

Comment: @debin Unexpected error.  Online example here: http://bit.ly/1IO8sMH